# Keyword not supported: '"data source'. in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlconnection

I'm running into this error

> (**[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: ''data source'.]**)

in my MVC app as I try to run a standard SQL Query in my controller without using EF. I've read other articles which talk about escaping quotes but that has not been of any avail thus far. My Connection code is as follows:

```
userDataQry = -->Long SQL Query contained in this variable <---;
connString ="\"Data Source = data.testdomain.com; Initial Catalog = DashboardData; IntegratedSecurity = True; Application Name = DMetricsApp; \"providerName=\"System.Data.SqlClient\"";
```

**C# Sql Connection Code:**

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using(SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(userDataQry, conn))
    {
        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sdp = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
        conn.Open();
        sdp.Fill(dt);

        if (dt != null)
        {
            list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }//End if
    }//End using
}//End using
```

Comment: Add the connection to the DB from VisualStudio and see the differences in the connection string which it will create in your Web.config

Comment: I followed the format of the default connection string in Web.Config, with the exception of name and AttachDbFileName properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the connection string

```
connString =@"Data Source=data.testdomain.com;
              Initial Catalog=DashboardData;
              IntegratedSecurity = True; 
              Application Name = DMetricsApp;";
```

Also remove the provider name part. It is not needed when you use the classes in *System.Data.SqlClient*

Comment: Made those adjustments you recommended and still getting the same error

Comment: Notice a possible typo *ConnString* declared but you used *connString* they are two different strings.

Comment: Do you still get that exception with **"Data Source...** still with a double quote before the Data Source key? If yes then something else is at play here. Check if you have other points where you set that string.

Comment: Yes. My connString matches your suggested fix. Still getting the same error. For the record. My connection strings in Web.Config are commented out when I'm testing this. This connection is within the body of a function in my Controller.

Comment: This is really weird, Data Source is absolutely a good key. Try to replace it with the alias **Server** (no quotes) See [SqlConnection.ConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unless... Did you copy/pasted that Data Source? Sometime you could get invalid blank chars if you copy from some web site. Try to delete the space between Data and Source and then retype it.

Comment: I tried the same connection string in a different project and its coming back with it "network path not found"

Comment: If you use that Data Source (data.testdomain.com) with Sql Server Management Studio, are you able to connect?

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing a Connection String it is basically shorthand for what the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class would create; but a problem can occur as it may do a split when you are using spaces both between the properties and within the property name when you use the **@** for a string literal

You could always do it the hard way:

```
string connstring = (new SqlConnectionStringBuilder() {
    DataSource = "data.testdomain.com;"
    , InitialCatalog = "DashboardData"
    , IntegratedSecurity = true
    , ApplicationName = "DMetricsApp"
    }).ToString();
```